# asp gridview visibility not triggered in select case

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, select-case

Within a vb asp.net webform I have a select case statement within a gridview databound procedure which is based on the values from a dropdown list as stored in a variable.

```
Protected Sub gvProgressGrid_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles gvProgressGrid.DataBound
    Dim strYear As String = DdlYear.Text
     Select Case strYear
        Case 11
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = True
        Case 10
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = True
        Case 9
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = True
        Case 8
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = False
        Case 7
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

As default the gridview displays and when I select 7 or 8 from the dropdown the gridview disappears ok. However, once disappeared if I select 9-11 then the grid doesn't reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the Databound event for your Gridview, I would use the SelectedIndexChanged event of your DropDownList to house this logic:

```
Protected Sub DdlYear_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DdlYear.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim strYear As String = DdlYear.Text
    Select Case strYear
        Case 11
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = True
        Case 10
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = True
        Case 9
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = True
        Case 8
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = False
        Case 7
            gvProgressGrid.Visible = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

This makes more sense, semantically, since the result is dependent on the value of of your dropdown (DdlYear.Text).

It also will probably function more correctly, as I imagine this problem has to do with how your GridView is databound (it's probably only databound on first page load, not on postbacks).